# How to access dataset defined in master page from user control on master page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a single master page with a dataset defined in VB code behind.

```
Public Property Inventory As DataSet = New DataSet
```

I populate the data in `Page_Init`.

I have a user control on the same master page. How can I access the dataset from the user control's code behind (*myusercontrol.ascx*) in `Page_Load`? I have no problem doing this with user controls on my content pages, but I can't get it to work when the control is on the master page.

Normally, I just reference it as `Master.Inventory`. That works when the control is on the content page, but how do I do that when the control is on the master page? I tried `Parent.Page.Master.Inventory`, `Page.Master.Inventory`, and even just `Inventory`. I get either "Inventory is not defined" or "Inventory is not a member of...".

In the user control, I'm just trying to do something like `Dim i As DataSet = [reference goes here]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a different route. I did everything directly from the master page.

I put a databound control inside my usercontrol (mine happened to be a `DropDownList`).

Then, I added a *DataBind* member to the user control *myusercontrol.ascx.vb*.

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property DataSource As DataTable
        Get
            Return MyDataBoundControl.DataSource
        End Get
        Set(ByVal _source As DataTable)
            MyDataBoundControl.DataSource = _source
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub DataBind
        MyDataBoundControl.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then on the master page *site.master*:

```
<MyPrefix:MyUserControl id="MyUserControl" runat="server" />
```

And in the master page code behind *site.master.vb*:

```
Dim DS As DataTable
[do some stuff to define and populate DS]

MyUserControl.DataSource = DS
MyUserControl.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your Master Page create a public property. In this case `myDataSet`

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public DataTable myDataSet { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add some dummy data to the dataset
        myDataSet = new DataTable();
        myDataSet.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        myDataSet.Columns.Add("COUNTRY", typeof(string));

        myDataSet.Rows.Add(0, "Netherlands");
        myDataSet.Rows.Add(1, "Japan");
        myDataSet.Rows.Add(2, "Country");
    }
}
```

Then in the Page_Load of the Control make a reference to the Master and then you can access that property.

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Site master;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the current master page
        master = (Site)Page.Master;

        //access the public property in the master
        Label1.Text = master.myDataSet.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    }
}
```

**VB**

I used a code translator for the VB so it may not be entirely correct. But you'll get the idea.

```
Public Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    
    Public Property myDataSet As DataTable
        Get
        End Get
        Set
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'add some dummy data to the dataset
        Me.myDataSet = New DataTable
        Me.myDataSet.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(System.Int32))
        Me.myDataSet.Columns.Add("COUNTRY", GetType(System.String))
        Me.myDataSet.Rows.Add(0, "Netherlands")
        Me.myDataSet.Rows.Add(1, "Japan")
        Me.myDataSet.Rows.Add(2, "Country")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Control

```
Public Class WebUserControl1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    
    Public master As Site
    
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'get the current master page
        Me.master = CType(Page.Master,Site)
        'access the public property in the master
        Label1.Text = Me.master.myDataSet.Rows(0)(1).ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. I ended up simplifying the requirement and going a different route though. I just did all the data manipulation directly in the master page and then databound the user control directly from the master page. I think sometimes I just make things too complicated.